# How to calculate average for each tumbling window?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I’m new in kafka streams and I’m really going crazy. I have a stream of counter values represented by `<counter-name, counter-value, timestamp>`. I want to calculate the average value for each day, like this:

**counterValues** topic content:

```
“cpu”, 10, “2022-06-03 17:00”
“cpu”, 20, “2022-06-03 18:00”
“cpu”, 30, “2022-06-04 10:00”
“memory”, 40, “2022-06-04 10:00”
```

and I want to obtain this output:

```
“cpu”, “2022-06-03”, 15
“cpu”, “2022-06-04”, 30
“memory”, “2022-06-04”, 40
```

This is a snippet of my code that it doesn’t work (it seems to calculate count)…

```
Duration windowSize = Duration.ofDays(1);
TimeWindows tumblingWindow = TimeWindows.of(windowSize);
counterValueStream
    .groupByKey().windowedBy(tumblingWindow)
    .aggregate(StatisticValue::new, (k, counterValue, statisticValue) -> {
        statisticValue.setSamplesNumber(statisticValue.getSamplesNumber() + 1);
        statisticValue.setSum(statisticValue.getSum() + counterValue.getValue());
        return statisticValue;
    }, Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), statisticValueSerde))
    .toStream().map((Windowed<String> key, StatisticValue sv) -> {
        double avgNoFormat = sv.getSum() / (double) sv.getSamplesNumber();
        double formattedAvg = Double.parseDouble(String.format("%.2f", avgNoFormat));
        return new KeyValue<>(key.key(), formattedAvg) ;
    }).to("average", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Double()));
```

But the aggregation result is:

```
“cpu”, 1, “2022-06-03 17:00”
“cpu”, 1, “2022-06-03 18:00”
“cpu”, 1, “2022-06-04 10:00”
“memory”, 1, “2022-06-04 10:00”
```

Note that I use a TimestampExtractor that use counter timestamp instead of kafka record. What am I doing wrong?